# What does Group By mean in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

What does **Group By** mean in *iReport* Report Wizard?

How does it different than SQL **Group By**?

Can I use SQL **Group By** and *iReport* **Group By** both or I need to use one of them?

Comment: Group by in IR report wizard let you combine records in group say for example area names in each city,yes you can surely use sql group by clause in IRreport grouping functionality

Comment: @HardikBhalani I asked .....can I use SQL Group BY  and IReport Group BY BOTH together ?

Comment: I mentioned that yes you can..tell me the scenario

Comment: @HardikBhalani  I'm asking because you know  if you have SQL Group BY  then it groups records ....so  if you do a group by with IReport Group By again ....is not this becoming two times group by then ? so  are you sure you can do SQL Group BY and IReport Group BY both together ?

Comment: as said sql group by and IR report group by is totally different things,you use group by in sql when you are using aggregate functions like max sum etc..e.g. you can arrange state report such that city A comes first having maximum no of areas,you have to use Group Header which will show your records such that city with maximum number of area comes first,in this query you will include city in GROUP BY clause and also include city in IR report group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Group by' in sql aggregates the result set so that the original tuples are not avaliable any more. 'Group by' in JR allows you to keep individual tuples and then aggregate the group of tuples.

The JR option allows the user to see both the total sum of a group and the individual components that make up the sum.

*tuple = single database row